# Flash firmware on a Micron OEM SSD (P400m)

Tags: ssd, firmware

I have a 100 GB Micron P400m SSD from an EMC VMAX array. The sector size is 520 or 528 bits. I can identify the drive with everything via the tools from Micron, but it refuses to download the firmware or even upload.

Is there a way to re-flash it with **different** *firmware*? I know [Crucial](https://store.cmsdistribution.com/ssd-enterprise/crucial-micron-p400m-200gb-sata-2.5-ssd/) or Cisco products of containing the same SSD drive allow such firmware updates.

**Edit:** additional information
Apparently there has micron MTFDDAK400MAN-**1**S1AA that has 512b blocks.  I have here micron MTFDDAK400MAN-**2**S1AA that has 520b blocks.

Is there anyone who could do a firmware dump from the micron MTFDDAK400MAN-1S1AA or perhaps where to download a 512b firmware for it?

Answer (score 1):

If taken out from an EMC array, it is very probable that your SSD uses a custom (or at least rebranded) firmware. This means that Micron/Crucial standard flashing tool can not work, requiring EMC's own utils/firmware.

Finally, please consider that not all SSDs support sector size changing (unless the vendor provides special utility to do that).

Comment: The SSD uses firmware directly from Micron which sets the block size on 520b, in that sense it is custom for the EMC array.  Since the disk is detected by the BIOS and OS only does not know how to handle it due to the block size, my idea was to take the *1* (512b) firmware and flash it to the *2* (520b) drive with `sg_write_buffer` (https://linux.die.net/man/8/sg_write_buffer).  (not using the std. tools from Micron/Crucial).  I have read that someone has been successful changing the sector size changing, but he left out how he did it.